# Server Software to stream Webcam to DLNA Digital Media Renderer

Tags: webcam, media, dlna

## Idea

I'm curious if it is possible to stream a webcam to an DLNA Digital Media Renderer...

Here's the idea:

- We have a webcam attached to a small server

  - running a DLNA Digital Media Server (DMS) (software?) streaming the webcam
  - running a DLNA Digital Media Controller (DMC) (software?) controlling the stream
- as soon as some motion is detected by the webcam

  - the DMC takes the video stream from the DMS an throws it to a DLNA Digital Media Renderer (DMR) (i.e. a fancy SmartTV)

IMHO this is similar to what happens, when  you use [iMediaShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bianor.ams) to get a Youtube video on you SmartTV.

## Motivation

Useful scenarios? Well, in MY case i want to add a video camera to a doorbell. And whenever someone rings and I'm watching TV, i see the video from the door. Additionally you can stream this to PCs and smartphones.

## Why i need you

I hope you like the idea, too, and have some information for me. Anything will do, but i prefer Open Source and Linux stuff, for the sake of customisation. I will add all useful information to this thread, so you may follow up, if you want.

Sorry for the poor tagging, but i can't use DMC or DMS. Do you have ideas?

## Useful Resources

### Information

- [DLNA on Wikipeda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance)

### Programs

Can't post links due to rep... will wait -.-

- [Coherence](http://coherence.beebits.net/): Seems outdated?
- [GUPnP](https://wiki.gnome.org/GUPnP/): looks nice, lib only? seems to be very big, and i didn't find information to DMC
- [Fuppes](http://www.ulrich-voelkel.de/software/fuppes/): Looks promising, but seems outdated. No DMC support?
- [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/): Looks promising, but lib only. After trying the Workbech I was able to control my TV. So this LIB will be checked for shure!
- [Brisa](http://brisa.garage.maemo.org/): Looks promising and big.
- [MiniDLNA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/): Seems it doesn't support what i want...